# Indexing a column in an ORDER BY that is dynamically obtained

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have an ORDER BY that is derived by a SELECT statement:

```
...
   WHERE col1 = ...
ORDER BY (SELECT CASE .. END) // - will return col2 or col3 both of which are in the same table as column 1.
```

Will the following indices be of use or does using the SELECT makes them useless?

```
INDEX (col1, col2)
INDEX (col1, col3)
```

Comment: One of this indices may be used for WHERE (dependent by table statistic), and none for ordering.

Comment: @Akina If I hardcode it as ... WHERE col1 = ... ORDER BY col2, then INDEX (col1, col2) is used?

Comment: Dependent by table statistic. If WHERE condition selects more than 5-7% of total records  and some another columns except `col1, col2` are selected then table scan may be less expensive than index scan + extract additional fields from table, and the index wil not be used.